# Laravel goutte form

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with Goutte submit the form. I'm trying to login to app, but every time when I refresh it's returning 404 error, but 404 in the app because as a final result I'm returning html() to see what is happening. Maybe 404 because my link is ex.

```
http://localhost:8000/trylogin
```

Here is the code.

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://app.productlistgenie.io/signin');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('LogIn')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('email' => 'myemail@here.com', 'password' => 'mypasshere'));
$crawler->filter('.flash-error')->each(function ($node) {
   print $node->text()."\n";
});

return $crawler->html();
```

Comment: Can you post the name of your controller function any your routes file?

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://app.productlistgenie.io/signin');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('SIGN IN')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('email' => 'myemail@here.com', 'password' => 'mypasshere'));
$crawler->filter('.font-roboto-light.color-dark-white')->each(function ($node) {
       print $node->text()."\n";
 });
return $crawler->html();
```